# SSO via SAML - avoid a step of clicking on a button corresponding to identity provider on the login screen

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

There are certain users in the org that have only SSO, as in they don't have a salesforce password set up.

Is there a way to send these users a link they can bookmark that directly goes to the step of verifying their SSO with the identity provider?

Basically, I want to them to skip having to click the login in with SSO button in the salesforce community login page.

I looked into it some more and is there a way to generate the SAML request link, the one that includes the SAML id?

Okay, I looked into it even more and got the same type of url through getSamlSsoUrl(communityUrl, startURL, samlId) from the AuthConfiguration class. However, when I click it, it gives an error. I think I may have to set up something before the link is active?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm

Comment: If this is SAML, use identity provider-initiated SSO, the link can/should come from the identity provider

Comment: It says "SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding."

Comment: Your IdP will have an IdP initiated Link. What IdP are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Azure

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your users to your SSO page when you open community URL, please follow the below-mentioned steps:

1. Open "My Domain" from quick find
2. Go to "Authentication Configuration" and click Edit.
3. Only Check the authentication page you want to show to your users and click save.

This will redirect users to your community SSO page when they click on community URL.